# Was bedeutet Mimomane bei Nietzsche?

Tags: meaning

Aus Nietzsches "Die Fröhliche Wissenschaft", Aphorismus 368.

> aber Wagner war […] der begeistertste Mimomane, den es gegeben hat, auch noch als Musiker! ([zeno.org](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Nietzsche,+Friedrich/Die+fr%C3%B6hliche+Wissenschaft/F%C3%BCnftes+Buch.+Wir+Furchtlosen/368.+Der+Zyniker+redet))

Answer (score 6):

Let us add some context. Nietzsche writes:

> Der Zyniker redet. – Meine Einwände gegen die Musik Wagners sind physiologische Einwände. [...] Was geht mich das Drama an! Was die Krämpfe seiner sittlichen Ekstasen, an denen das »Volk« seine Genugtuung hat! Was der ganze Gebärden-Hokus-pokus des Schauspielers!... Man errät, ich bin wesentlich antitheatralisch geartet – aber Wagner war umgekehrt wesentlich Theatermensch und Schauspieler, der begeistertste Mimomane, den es gegeben hat, auch noch als Musiker!... Und, beiläufig gesagt: wenn es Wagners Theorie gewesen ist »das Drama ist der Zweck, die Musik ist immer nur dessen Mittel« – seine Praxis dagegen war, von Anfang bis zu Ende, »die Attitüde ist der Zweck, das Drama, auch die Musik ist immer nur ihr Mittel«. Die Musik als Mittel zur Verdeutlichung, Verstärkung, Verinnerlichung der dramatischen Gebärde und Schauspieler-Sinnenfälligkeit; und das Wagnersche Drama nur eine Gelegenheit zu vielen dramatischen Attitüden!

In short Nietzsche says, that he likes music, but he "hates" play-acting and theater in general. He says, that Wagner on the other hand is a "fan" of (over-)acting, drama and that the music serves the acting/drama, while Nietzsche likes pure music without any acting.

Mimomane can be compared to words like Egomane or Pyromane, with mane as a [suffix  which is](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-mane)

> Forming compound nouns with the sense ‘person who has a mania for’.

Like a Pyromane (pyromaniac) has a mania for fire and a Egomane (egomaniac) a mania for himself.

Mimo seems to be derived from the latin word [mimus](https://www.frag-caesar.de/lateinwoerterbuch/MIMO-uebersetzung.html) (actor), so Nietzsch says, that

> Wagner is a maniac for (over-)acting / actors / theater

## Deutsch:

Schaut man auf den ganzen Absatz, wird deutlich, dass Nietzsche eine Abneigung gegen das Theater und die "Gebärden" der Schauspieler hat. Er ist "antitheatralisch geartet". Wagner auf der anderen Seite ist für ihn völlig anders. Dieser verehrt das Theater und nutzt die Musik als Mittel, um die Schauspielerei und das Theater dramatischer zu gestalten.

Das Wort Mimomane ist ähnlich gebildet wie Worte wie Pyromane oder Egomane. Das Suffix -mane [bedeutet hier](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_mane)

> eine Person, die auf etwas fast suchtartig fixiert, ganz versessen ist

Das Wort Mimo hat seinen Ursprung vom lateinischen Wort mimus (Schauspieler), das auch als [Mime](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mime_Schauspieler) Einzug in die deutsche Sprache fand. In einzelnen Schriftstücken gibt es auch Begriffe wie [Mimologe oder Mimoden](https://books.google.de/books?id=gQXs4s7orkMC&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=mimologen&source=bl&ots=sQaZEpwKH4&sig=ACfU3U3eSv4fo_U5pcoBOF0EalIxlKmoAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgq6Xo2pTmAhVN_aQKHSSxC40Q6AEwA3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=mimologen&f=false), die sich auf verschiedene Arten antiker Schauspieler beziehen. In wie weit diese Begriffe verbreitet waren mag ich nicht beurteilen.

Betrachtet man das Wort Mimomane unter diesen Aspekten zeigt sich, dass Nietzsche damit einen

> von Schauspielerei/Theater/Drama besessenen Mann

bezeichnet.

Comment: There is an antiquated German word for actor: *Mime*, which is obviously also derived from the Latin word. This word should have been in use at Nietzsche's time, so he could expect that his readers would understand his *Mimomane*

Comment: Since the original question in in German, could you provide a German translation for this otherwise excellent answer?

Comment: Gute Antwort. Grundsätzlich gilt: um die Bedeutung eines Wortes bei Nietzsche zu verstehen, muss man vor allem Nietzsche lesen.

Comment: @Olafant Man sollte in diesem Fall auch den historischen Kontext sehen. Dass "Mimomane" nicht als Kompliment gemeint ist, erschließt sich schon aus dem Text. Die wirklich negative Konnotation habe ich in meiner Antwort dargestellt.

Answer (score 2):

Der Begriff "Mimomanie" wurde nicht von Nietzsche erfunden, sondern geht auf die Brüder Goncourt zurück. Ich empfehle einen Blick in

> Historischer und kritischer Kommentar zu Friedrich Nietzsches Werken / Kommentar zu Nietzsches "Der Antichrist", "Ecce homo", "Dionysos-Dithyramben" und "Nietzsche contra Wagner"

von Andreas Urs Sommer.

Das Goncourt-Zitat stammt aus "La femme au dix-huitieme siecle". Hier erhält man auch eine Erklärung: Mimomanie ist die Vorliebe, Kömodie zu spielen. (Le goût de jouer la comédie gagne toutes les classes.) Allerdings ist dies stark negativ konnotiert. Die Vorliebe befällt alle Klassen wie eine Raserei, ein Wahnsinn.

[image]

Hier noch ein längeres Zitat aus

> Der Marquis de Sade und seine Zeit. Ein Beitrag zur Kultur- und Sittengeschichte des 18. Jahrhunderts. Mit besonderer Beziehung auf die Lehre von der Psychopathia sexualis

von Eugen Dühren, das die Wortbedeutung in einen größeren Zusammenhang stellt. Wagner als den "begeistertsten Mimomanen, den es gegeben hat" zu bezeichnen, attestiert ihm, der größte Dilettant aller Zeiten zu sein.

> Wie sehr der Marquis de Sade ein 
>   Mensch seiner Zeit war, der nur aus ihr erklärt werden 
>   kann, zeigt vor allem der Umstand, dass auch er von 
>   jener dem 18. Jahrhundert eigentümlichen Manie ergriffen 
>   war: der Theaterwut, der Mimomanie! de Sade 
>   hat nicht nur zahlreiche Theaterstücke geschrieben, sondern 
>   auch dilettantische Theateraufführungen veranstaltet.
>
> Die Leidenschaft des Theaterspielens, die „Mimomanie“, herrschte in Frankreich während des ganzen 
>   Jahrhunderts mit einer uns heute kaum verständlichen 
>   Macht. Überall im Lande bildeten sich förmliche Dilettantengesellscbaften. Ein Haustheater gehörte zu jedem 
>   Schloss, zu jedem vornehmen Haus. „Es ist eine unglaubliche Manie“, heisst es in Bachaumont’s Memoiren, 
>   „selbst jeder Prokurator will in seinem Landhäuschen 
>   eine Gauklerbühne und eine Komödientruppe haben.“ 
>   Sogar in die Kreise des Klerus drang die Theaterwut. 
>   Durch die Pompadour wurde das Theaterspielen am Hofe 
>   Ludwig’s XV. eingeführt. „Die Damen studieren mit 
>   den Schauspielern die Stücke ein, die sie auf ihrer Privatbühne aufführen. Es war so lustig, bot so viel Stoff 
>   zu niedlichen Intriguen und galanten Erlebnissen, den 
>   bunten Flitter des Pierrot und der Colombine zu tragen.“

Zum Abschluss noch der Hinweis auf

> Mimomania - Music and Gesture in Nineteenth Century Opera (California Studies in 19th-Century Music, Band 13

von Mary Ann Smart. Zitat aus dem in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270819281_Mimomania_Music_and_Gesture_in_Nineteenth-Century_Opera zu findenden Abstract der Verfasserin:

> When Nietzsche dubbed Richard Wagner "the most enthusiastic mimomaniac" ever to exist, he was objecting to a hollowness he felt in the music, a crowding out of any true dramatic impulse by extravagant poses and constant nervous movements.

Comment: Da die Frage nach der Bedeutung des Wortes war, ist das wohl eher ein Kommentar als eine Antwort.

Comment: @DavidVogt Da hast Du wohl Recht, aber da es schwierig sein dürfte, das Zitat-Bild in einen Kommentar einzubinden, sollten wir das ausnahmsweise mal durchgehen lassen.

Comment: @DavidVogt Ich habe mir erlaubt, meinen Beitrag noch deutlich zu erweitern. Ich hoffe, damit zur Klärung der Wortbedeutung beigetragen zu haben